# The role and the meaning of 才 inside 司机及时停车,才避免了一起交通事故。

Tags: grammar

> 司机及时停车,才避免了一起交通事故。

司机及时停车 = The driver stopped his car timely.

Ignoring 才 , 才避免了一起交通事故 can be translated as "avoided a traffic accident completely".

Above both translations were done by myself by the way.

I've been confusing understanding the role and the meaning of 才 here.

Comment: Now i knew that 一起 which is used here works as a measure word lol. Had thought that this word is of "together, completely".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

司机及时停车，避免了一起交通事故。 = The driver stopped the car in time, (and) avoided a traffic accident.

司机及时停车[**才**]避免了一起交通事故。 = The driver avoided a traffic accident [**only because**] he stopped the car in time

[才] marks [司机及时停车] as the condition and [避免了一起交通事故] as the result

Another example:

有錢買車 = Have money to buy a car

有錢[**才**]買車 = Buy a car [**only when**] I have money

[才] marks [有錢] as the condition and [買車] as the result

Answer (score 1):

才 is a particle for conditional clauses, similar to **only by**.

Depending on the reading, 及时停车 or 司机及时停车 is **the** condition that ensured 避免了一起交通事故. The first reading has the subject 司机 for the whole sentence, and translates as **the drive avoided a traffic accident only by stopping the car in time**. The second reading has the subject 司机 for the first clause and the event 司机及时停车 as the condition while 避免 has no subject. It translates as **only by the fact that the driver stopped the car in time was a traffic accident avoided.**

Without 才, the sentence is just a simple clause with a complicate predicate, *the driver stopped the car in time and avoided a traffic accident*.

Answer (score 1):

司机及时停车，**才**避免了一起交通事故。= **幸亏**司机及时停车，**才**避免了一起交通事故。= We did not involve in the accident **only because** the driver stopped the vehicle in time.

**幸亏--，才--**，= It is only because -- that --. This is a very popular sentence structure. Sometimes people just omit **幸亏** for short.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use 多亏 ··· 才··· together

多亏司机及时停车，才避免了一起交通事故。
Thanks to the driver's timely halt, a traffic accident was averted.

多亏她，我才抱住性命。
Thanks to her, I am still alive.